# Prove that the given space $H^1$ is not complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. For $u, v \in C^1(\overline{\Omega}) $, define
$$
(u,v)_{H^1} = \int_{\Omega} u(x)v(x)dx + \int_{\Omega}\nabla u(x)\cdot \nabla v(x)dx.
$$
I want to show that $(C^1(\Omega), (\cdot,\cdot)_{H^1})$ is an inner product space but not complete.
I've already proved that $(u,v)$ is an inner product function, but I have no clue on how to prove that it is not complete.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempts

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Try for $n=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$

Comment: Take an easy nondifferentiable function like $|x|$ and approximate with smooth functions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114070/how-to-prove-that-ck-omega-is-not-complete?rq=1

Comment: It is somehow alike to the sobolev space with a different norm. And the form of its norm is alike to the norm of $L^p$, my idea is trying to construct a continuous function sequence converges in norm while its limit function is not continuous.